# Can one directive have different names in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having two directives with same functionality like below.

```
angular.module('ui.directives', [])
  .directive('uiFoo', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          //to do functionality
          element.append("test content");
        }
       };
    })
  .directive('uiFoo1', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          //to do functionality
          element.append("test content");
        }
      };
    });
```

They both contain the same working like here it is appending "test content" as text to that element.
Is there any chance that instead making this two directive. Can i write two names for one directive/ I can use same functionality in with optimize code.
Here I'm writing same code for without any meaning.
Instead of writing directive two times, is there any optimize way.
I'm new in AngularJS kindly help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you doit in the same directive making it more configurable?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want both directives to do exactly the same?

Comment: @PSL i want to apply directive for input and select element.and both wil have same functionality..then how should achieve it?

Comment: You don't need them to have different names to do that.

Comment: @pankajparkar You can do away with just one directive. What exactly are you doing in the directive(s)?

Comment: Actually my requirement was, i have one form and they contain many select and input element..I want to keep a track on which element is updated in last time.and want to store id of them?
So that's why i thought directive may help me..I wrote directive for input and select and then on blur i was catching the id of element..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simpliest way would be to extract your directive into a JS object and use this instead.

Alternativly you can provide the directive object with a angular provider, if you want to stay in the angular context.

But, why do you want to have two directives with the exact same functionality in the first place?
Directives can used as often as you want, so this seems like a design flaw to me.

```
var myDirective = [function(){
            restrict: 'EAC',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
              //to do functionality
              element.append("test content");
            }
          }];

angular.module('ui.directives', [])
      .directive('uiFoo', myDirective)
      .directive('uiFoo1', myDirective);
```

Comment: Why not set myDirective = function()... Then, if you need to inject dependencies, you only have to do it once.  Note that to be minifiable, you would return an array eg. myDirective = ['$http', function($http)...]

Comment: Of course you can extract the whole function too. I'll change the answer accordingly.